# How to predict timeseries using an existing one and then compare in terms of residual using R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm quite new to R. I have a time-series data which I plotted simply by

```
plot(ts(data))
```

A snapshot of the plot can be found here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vclo2WWg4TTJaMGs/edit?usp=sharing

I have read a few of articles regarding forecasting time-series, but those explanations have too many dimensions and I'm not really sure which one to follow!! Is there any step by step procedure to produce the predicted time-series from the original data and then compare those on the basis of residual? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this tuorial: http://msenux.redwoods.edu/math/R/regression.php

Comment: looking at your plot..I see no obvious trend ,no obvious seasonality, maybe some cycles..I think it will be hard to difficult to do something with this ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(data)
fcast <- forecast(fit)
accuracy(fcast)
```

Detailed explanations can be found at http://otexts.com/fpp/